# TDA7575B Based Audio Amplifier Problem

Tags: amplifier

I have designed a [TDA7575B](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00175174-1796848.pdf) based audio amplifier, see attached screenshot image. The tone control as configured, will the input signal not be below standard 2v line input voltage that the TDA would typically be used with? I dont know how to add a preamp. Can someone please clarify[image] or help me to get it designed.
I apologies and I am new to electronics.

Comment: What are the details of the sources you expect to apply? ("Standard line input" isn't exactly an exact standard... there are several, memory serving.) And yes, all that tone control stuff will definitely attenuate your input signal before it reaches the TDA. And as its maximum voltage gain appears to suggest what you wrote (I get about 1.75 Vpp input needed to reach full power output into 2 Ohms using 18 V as Vcc), I tend to agree about the idea of a pre-amp stage with a volume control. I didn't quickly spot a volume control in the TDA. But maybe I missed it.

Comment: Draw the circuit in a simulator and analyze it to see if it works without.